# Nonlinear Poisson brackets associated with nilpotent (matrix) Lie algebras?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, poisson-geometry

With every finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ one can associate a linear Poisson bracket on $\mathfrak{g}^\ast$. With some more restrictions on $\mathfrak{g}$ and some extra ingredients, there are other constructions of linear, *quadratic* and *cubic* Poisson brackets associated with $\mathfrak{g}$: see [*Nonlinear Poisson structures and $r$-matrices*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-125/issue-4/Nonlinear-Poisson-structures-and-r-matrices/cmp/1104179627.full) by Li–Parmentier (1989) or §10.3 in the book [*Poisson Structures*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-31090-4) by Vanhaecke et al (2013).

The quadratic and cubic constructions assume in particular that $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of an associative algebra, and that $\mathfrak{g}$ is equipped with a non-degenerate symmetric bi-linear map $\langle \cdot | \cdot \rangle$ which satisfies $\langle xy | z\rangle = \langle x | yz\rangle$ for all $x,y,z \in \mathfrak{g}$.
For example, $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\langle x | y \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(xy)$.

Now, e.g., for the Lie algebra of strictly upper-triangular matrices, the trace form is zero identically which is very degenerate, so the aforementioned quadratic and cubic constructions do not work.

**Question:** Is there a construction of a *nonlinear* Poisson bracket associated with a *nilpotent* finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$?

I doubt there is such a construction generalizing the previously mentioned ones, so I rather ask if there is any (different) construction specific (or applicable) to the nilpotent case.